# Math.random function not properly working in javascript with if statement

Tags: javascript

In my function I'm generating a random number using Math.random, then with an if statement I want it show an alert if it rolls over 1 in this case, this is my code :

```
    function Enemy(x,y){

        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.speed=5;
        this.width=30;
        this.height=30;

        return Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
            if (Math.random() > 1) {
                alert(booyah);

            }

    }
```

Now, I don't get any alert when I open the page. If I in the console use Enemy(); I get a number, so that's working fine.

Comment: Is it not working because `random()` is never bigger than 1, or because it is after a `return` statement? Or maybe `booyah` is not defined? What should it do? There are so many bugs in just three lines of code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once function hits return statement it's the end of function so if statement is ignored. Try assignining math.random to a variable and make if statement before return.

```
function Enemy(x,y){

    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.speed=5;
    this.width=30;
    this.height=30;

    var random = Math.random();

        if (random > 1) {
            alert(booyah);

        }

    return Math.floor((random * 100) + 1);


}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 return Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
            if (Math.random() > 1) {
                alert(booyah);

            }
```

no code can ever be executed after a return statement;

Answer (score 0):

It wont get in to if block if its already returned above it.